# Second Derivative involving exponentials?

Tags: derivatives

Calculate the second derivative of $h ()   = e^{−( − 1)^2}.$

My answer is $4(x-1)^2 e^{-(x-1)^2}$.

My working was to initially get the derivative from the $[-(x-1)^2]$ and times it back with $e$ . Then i repeat the same process.

Is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: Please use mathJaX format when posting to this site, but unfortunately you will have to use the product rule for the second derivative, not just the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Your second derivative is not correct. Note that the first derivative is
$$h'(x)=D(e^{−( − 1)^2})=-2(x-1)e^{−( − 1)^2}.$$
Now, for the second derivative $h''(x)$, you have evaluate the derivative of the above **product**: 
$$h''(x)=D(-2(x-1))e^{−( − 1)^2}-2(x-1)D(e^{−( − 1)^2}).$$
Check your result, a term is missing!

Comment: Thank you very much everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Differentiaitng $e^{g(x)}$ leads to $g'(x)e^{g(x)}$, and differentiating this again leads to $(g''(x)+\{g'(x)\}^2)e^{g(x)}$. Thus here the second derivative of $e^{-(x-1)^2}$ is $(4x^2-8x+2)e^{-(x-1)^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Put $$h (x)=e^{f (x)} $$

then

$$h'(x)=f'(x)h (x) $$
and

$$h''(x)=(f''(x)+(f'(x))^2)h (x) $$

with $$f (x)=-(x-1)^2,$$

we find

$$f'(x)=-2 (x-1)\;\;\; f''(x)=-2$$

thus
$$h''(x)=(-2+4 (x-1 )^2)e^{-(x-1)^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

**A small answer:**

No, you are not doing it right!!! :P

---

**A better explanation:**

The chain rule states that,

$$\frac{d}{dx}(f(g(x))=\frac{df}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}$$
Also we know that,
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^x)=e^x$$
Now let your function be $f(g(x))=e^g$, where $g(x)=-(x-1)^2$. So
$$\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{d}{dg}(e^g)=e^g$$and
$$\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\left[-(x-1)^2\right]=-2(x-1)$$
So$$\begin{align}\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}=-2(x-1)e^g&=-2(x-1)e^{-(x-1)^2}\\
&=y(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (say)\end{align}$$
Now we calculate $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}$ which is equal to $\displaystyle\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$. Now let $y=u(x)v(x)$ where, $u(x)=-2(x-1)$ and $v(x)=e^{-(x-1)^2}$. Hence $\displaystyle{\frac{du}{dx}=-2}$ and $\displaystyle{\frac{dv}{dx}=-2(x-1)e^{-(x-1)^2}}$.

Now by [the product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule),
$$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[u(x)v(x)\right]\\
&=\frac{du}{dx}v+u\frac{dv}{dx}\\
&=(-2)\left[e^{-(x-1)^2}\right]+\left[-2(x-1)\right]\left[-2(x-1)e^{-(x-1)^2}\right]\\
&=-2e^{-(x-1)^2}+4(x-1)^2e^{-(x-1)^2}\\
&=e^{-(x-1)^2}\left[-2+4(x-1)^2\right]\\
&=(4x^2-8x+2)e^{-(x-1)^2}
\end{align}$$
which is the correct answer.

Comment: Don't you think it is too long.

Comment: The  longer an explanation, the better. That's my opinion. :P

Comment: You asked the question, so you should be expecting some long answers....